# facebook graph API emoticons encoding

Tags: php, facebook, encoding

I use the facebook PHP SDK to get a pages feed and display it on an external website.
Fetching the data works well, but I can't display the emoticons correctly. It looks like I am using special chars in the wrong charset. I think there are codes for emoticons in the unicode standard.

This is what I get:

I already tried utf8_encode(), but that does not solve the problem.
Any ideas? I would like to get any code I can use for further actions like replacing ...